# Reidemeister Moves I II and III

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-knots

Im looking for a simple solution to draw the Reidemeister-Moves.
I have difficulties to show the intersections.
Is there a simple way to display the intersections?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
\begin{center} %1
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={15mm}, thick, main/.style = {draw, circle,scale=0.8}] 
\draw (0,0) to [out = -10, in = -90](2,.5) to [out=90, in = 90, looseness = 1.5] (1,.5) [out=-90, in = -170]to (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace*{.1in}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={15mm}, thick, main/.style = {draw, circle,scale=0.8}] 
\draw (0,0) to [out = -10, in = -170] (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace*{.1in}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={15mm}, thick, main/.style = {draw, circle,scale=0.8}] 
\draw (0,0) to [out = -10, in = -90](2,.5) to [out=90, in = 90, looseness = 1.5] (1,.5) [out=-90, in = -170]to (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\begin{center} %2
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={15mm}, thick, main/.style = {draw, circle,scale=0.8}] 
\draw[red] (0,0) to [out =10 , in = 110] (2,-0.5) to [out =-70, in = 70, looseness=1] (2,-1.5) to [out =-110, in = -10] (0,-2);
\draw[blue] (4,-.25) to [out = 170, in = 70] (2,-.5) to  [out =-110, in= 110] (2,-1.5) to   [out =-70, in = 190]  (4,-1.75);
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace*{.2in}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={15mm}, thick, main/.style = {draw, circle,scale=0.8}] 
\draw[red] (0,0) to [out =10 , in = 110] (2,-0.5) to [out =-70, in = 70, looseness=1] (2,-1.5) to [out =-110, in = -10] (0,-2);
\draw[blue] (4,-.25) to [out = 170, in = 70] (2.5,-.5) to  [out =-110, in= 110] (2.5,-1.5) to   [out =-70, in = 190]  (4,-1.75);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\begin{center} %3
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={15mm}, thick, main/.style = {draw, circle,scale=0.8}] 
\draw[red] (0,0) to (2,-2);
\draw[blue] (2,0) to (0,-2);
\draw[green] (0,-.5) to (2,-.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace*{.1in}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={15mm}, thick, main/.style = {draw, circle,scale=0.8}] 
\draw[red] (0,0) to (2,-2);
\draw[blue] (2,0) to (0,-2);
\draw[green] (0,-1.5) to (2,-1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace*{.3in}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={15mm}, thick, main/.style = {draw, circle,scale=0.8}] 
\draw[blue] (0,0) to (2,-2);
\draw[red] (2,0) to (0,-2);
\draw[green] (0,-.5) to (2,-.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace*{.1in}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={15mm}, thick, main/.style = {draw, circle,scale=0.8}] 
\draw[blue] (0,0) to (2,-2);
\draw[red] (2,0) to (0,-2);
\draw[green] (0,-1.5) to (2,-1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This could be my goal or something similar:

[image]
This is my current state:
[image]
Thanks!

Comment: You could use tikz-knots - a package you yourself have added as a tag.

Comment: @hpekristiansen I dont really unterstand how I can use this package to get the wished result

Answer (score 4):

The `knots` package can automate much of this, but here is a manual solution that uses the same basic technique.

To make the crossings, draw the bottom strand first, then draw the top strand with option `double` where `double distance` is set to the same thickness as the line width. The `line width` within `double` draws a thick white line, with a thin black (or your choice of color)  line on top, simulating an overcrossing. This is built into a style called `overcross` in the code below. To change the spacing around the top strand, change `line width=1.5`.

I made each piece into its own `tikzpicture` with an optional argument so they can be reused. For example, the leftmost Type I figure is the same as the rightmost, but mirrored along the x-axis. So using `yscale=-1` produces the desired effect. Similarly, the Type III moves are just rotated and mirrored versions of the leftmost image.

The line width in the diagrams is set globally with `\knotlinewidth`. Of course you can change the thickness however you like.

Finally, I added the `enumitem` package to make the Roman numerals easy.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\tikzset{overcross/.style={double, line width=1.5, white, double=#1, double distance=\knotlinewidth},
    overcross/.default={black},
    knot/.style={line width=\knotlinewidth, baseline=-.5ex}}

\newcommand{\knotlinewidth}{.7pt}
\newcommand{\myarrow}{$\quad\longleftrightarrow\quad$}
\newcommand{\RIa}[1][]{\tikz[knot, #1]{\draw(-.5,.5) to[out=-90,in=-90] (.5,0); \draw[overcross] (.5,0) to[out=90,in=90] (-.5,-.5);}}
\newcommand{\RIb}[1][]{\tikz[knot, #1]{\draw[looseness=.8] (-.5,-.5) to[out=90, in=-90] (.5,0) to[out=90, in=-90] (-.5,.5);}}
\newcommand{\RIIa}[1][]{\tikz[knot, #1]{\draw[red, looseness=2.3] (-.5,-.5) to[out=0, in=0] (-.5,.5); \draw[looseness=2.3, overcross=blue] (.5,-.5) to[out=180, in=180] (.5,.5);}}
\newcommand{\RIIb}[1][]{\tikz[knot, #1]{\draw[red, looseness=1.4] (-.5,-.5) to[out=0, in=0] (-.5,.5);\draw[blue, looseness=1.4] (.5,.5) to[out=180,in=180] (.5,-.5);}}
\newcommand{\RIIc}[1][]{\tikz[knot, #1]{\draw[blue, looseness=2.3] (.5,-.5) to[out=180, in=180] (.5,.5); \draw[looseness=2.3, overcross=red] (-.5,-.5) to[out=0,in=0] (-.5,.5);}}
\newcommand{\RIIIa}[1][]{\tikz[knot, #1]{\draw[red] (-120:.58) to[out=60,in=-120] (150:.2) to[out=60, in=-120] (60:.58); \draw[rotate=-120, overcross=blue] (-120:.58) to[out=60, in=-120] (150:.2) to[out=60, in=-120] (60:.58); \draw[rotate=120, overcross=green!80!black] (-120:.58) to[out=60, in=-120] (150:.2) to[out=60, in=-120] (60:.58);}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Roman*)]
\item \RIa\myarrow\RIb\myarrow\RIa[yscale=-1]
\item \RIIa\myarrow\RIIb\myarrow\RIIc
\item \RIIIa\myarrow\RIIIa[rotate=180]\qquad\RIIIa[xscale=-1]\myarrow\RIIIa[xscale=-1, rotate=180]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to have different colors for the separate parts?